# How to return array of arrays, with different sizes form function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create array of arrays with different sizes and return it, so I can work with it later. Is it even possible? I was trying to do something like this:

```cc
#include <iostream>

int* fun(){
    int a[] = {3, 2, 1};
    int b[] = {5, 4};
    int *arr[] = {a, b};

    return *arr;
}

int main() {
    int *array = fun();
    printf("\n%d, %d, %d", *(array), *(array + 1), *(array + 2));
    // this one prints: 3, 2, 1
    printf("\t%d, %d", *(array + 3), *(array + 4));
    // this one prints random numbers
    return 0;
}
```

I want to access both arrays.

Comment: Use a std::vector instead of this.

Comment: use std::vector instead - the arrays you are trying to return are local to the function, and so the pointer you  are trying to return will be invalid. also, how is the calling function supposed to know the dimension of the array?

Comment: You can use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead.

Comment: ***I want to access both arrays.*** All 3 arrays no longer exist when the function ends. The returned pointer is invalid and we call it a dangling pointer.

Comment: c-arrays cannot be returned from functions. Same for arrays of arrays

Comment: @4630 well, they can be if they were dynamically allocated, though i agree this is a bad idea

Comment: @NeilButterworth you can return a pointer to first element, bad idea because you dont know the size. You can wrap it in a custom type together with the size, but then you are just reinventing `std::vector` ;)

Comment: @NeilButterworth imho it is important to distinguish between the array and pointer to first element. The type of the array "knows" the size, the pointer not. The array you cannot return, the pointer yes

Comment: @4630 yes indeed, but a c-style array doesn't know its size either, and they are widely used. and  something like "return new X[n];" is not impossible, just toxic. probably best to leave it there

Comment: @NeilButterworth c-style arrays know their size.  We can even get it using `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` or just `std::size(array)`

Comment: @Nathan i would say the compiler knows the size, not the array, and in any case i meant dynamically allocated c-style arrays, rather than something like std::array or std::vector. anyway, enuf?

Comment: @NeilButterworth the size is part of its type. `int[4]` for example is an array type, `int*` isnt ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would refactor to use `std::vector` instead of c-style arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<int>> fun(){
    std::vector<int> a{3, 2, 1};
    std::vector<int> b{5, 4};
    return {a, b};
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> values = fun();
    printf("\n%d, %d, %d", values[0][0], values[0][1], values[0][2]);
    printf("\t%d, %d", values[1][0], values[1][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can also simplify to `return {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 4}};` to get guaranteed RVO